# Pyramid - uploading images and storing on disk

Tags: python, image, pyramid, uploading

I'm trying to implement a system of uploading a file (image) to the server running pyramid. Right now, this code gives me an `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'file'` exception:

Server-side:

```
session = Session()
username = authenticated_userid(request)
if username == None:
    return HTTPNotFound()
else:
    user = session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
if 'photo.submitted' in request.params:
    input_file = request.POST['file_input'].file
    tmp = '../static/images/%s' % (session.query(ProfilePic).order_by(-ProfilePic.photo_id).first().photo_id + 1)
    open(tmp, 'w').write(input_file.read())
    tmp.close()
    return Response('OK')
return {}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/settings" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="file_input" value="Choose image" />


    <p><input type="submit" name="photo.submitted" value="Save" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Something that seems simple, but won't work. I was trying to follow [this](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/static_assets/files.html) tutorial, but it seems it only works with video/audio files. How could I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For file uploads, you need to alter the form enctype to use [`multipart/form-data`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-html-fileupload-02):

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/settings" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file_input" value="Choose image" />


    <p><input type="submit" name="photo.submitted" value="Save" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh wow. I feel so stupid. It was right in front of my face the whole time.